# Error when reading in SAS file in R

Tags: r, r-haven

I try to read in a SAS file using the `haven` package in R.

However, when I try to read a file like this:

```
read_sas("query_for_dm_abonnement_detail1.sas7bdat")
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Failed to parse   \\sassmnetl\saseguide\EGuide_Users\M.van.der.Peet\query_for_dm_abonnement_detail    1.sas7bdat: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features.
```

And that is strange because when I try to load in another file with `read.sas7bdat`, it works, i.e.

```
df <- read.sas7bdat("filter_for_dm_abonnement_detail.sas7bdat")
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Try to run the below file ("filter_for_dm_abonnement_detail.sas7bdat") using function read_sas, do it shows same error as you shown two different files